# MonoTouch UITableView PushViewController

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, pushviewcontroller

I'm using an `UITableView` with the following setup:

- normal mode: detail disclosure button
- edit mode: disclosure indicator

If the table is in edit mode and I select the row, the `pushViewController(nextViewController,animated)` is called.

**But now my problem**: During the animated change of the view controller, the disclosure button **changes to a detail disclosure button**.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share some code? No code, no solution...

Comment: of course: public void showDetail(){  this.NavigationController.PushViewController(_InstrumentViewController,true);} and before i call _Table.WillBegintEditing()

Comment: I don't think the HIG directly addresses this, but it seems non-standard to push a viewcontroller when your table is in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that iOS cancels "editing mode" before it pushes the next view controller.